# Laravel update based on if statement

Tags: php, laravel

I am newbie to laravel and currently developing a small App as part of my learning. I am stuck and I need some help.

The DB looks like this

```
USER
- Id
- Name

PRODUCT
- id
- Name
- quantity
- price

PRODUCT_USER
- id
- user_id
- product_id
- quantity
```

On `INSERT` of a new `PRODUCT_USER` record – I managed to validate/check if the quantity entered is not greater than the quantity from products, this is working fine.

**My struggle**:

On Update of `PRODUCT_USER` – if the new quantity value is greater than the old quantity value it means I am adding products to the current quantity value, update (by subtracting) the quantity (from products table) if products are still available.

If the new quantity value is less that the old quantity value it means I am returning some products to be assigned to a different user. Add to the quantity (from products table) the new quantity value.

```
ProductUserController 
public function update(Request $request, $id){ 
$productUser = ProductUser::where('id',$id)->first(); 
$product = Product::where('id',$productUser->product_id)->first(); 

if($product->quantity >= $request->get('quantity'))
{ 
$product->quantity= $product->quantity + $productUser->quantity - $request->get('quantity'); 
$product->update(); 
$productUser->quantity = $request->get('quantity'); 
$productUser->update(); 
return redirect()->route('allocations.index')->with('success','Updated');
} 

return redirect()->route('allocations.index')->with('message','Not enough qty'); }
```

Comment: Please show us what have you done so far.

Comment: ProductUserController
public function update(Request $request, $id){
$productUser = ProductUser::where('id',$id)->first();
$product = Product::where('id',$productUser->product_id)->first();
if($product->quantity >= $request->get('quantity')){
$product->quantity= $product->quantity + $productUser->quantity - $request->get('quantity');
$product->update();
$productUser->quantity = $request->get('quantity');
$productUser->update();
return redirect()->route('allocations.index')->with('success','Updated');}
return redirect()->route('allocations.index')->with('message','Not enough qty');
}

Comment: Please add it in a readable format.

Comment: I didn't have enough space to paste the code on my controller, I squashed everything there.

Comment: I have added the code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you're question correctly, you can achieve this by doing something like this (code not tested):

```
public function updateProductUser(Request $request) {

    $userQuantityTotal = 0;

    $product = Product::find($request->productid);

    if (!$product) {
        die('product not found');
    }

    $productUser = $product->users()->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);

    if ($productUser->exists()) {
        $userQuantityTotal = ($request->quantity + $productUser->quantity);
    } else {
        $userQuantityTotal = $request->quantity;
    }

    if ($userQuantityTotal > $product->quantity) {
        die('this amount is not available');
    }

    $product->quantity -= $request->quantity;
    $product->save();

    if ($productUser->exists()) {
        $productUser->quantity += $request->quantity;
        $productUser->save();
    } else {
        $product->users()->create([
            'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
            'quantity' => $request->quantity
        ])
    }

    return redirect()->route('route.name')->with('success', 'Success msg');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I will make necessary modifications to the code .. it is definitely pointing me in the right direction.

I thank you. I will post my final code when done.